# Php Array list items with different class

Tags: php

This is my current array that displays list items in a unordered list.

```
function get_bottle_colors() {
    if(empty($_GET['cap_id'])) return false;
    $constructor_img = get_post_meta($_GET['cap_id'], 'product_constructor_image', true);
    if(is_array($constructor_img) && count($constructor_img)>0 && !empty($constructor_img[0]['title'])){
        $output = '<label>Bottle Color</label><ul>';
            foreach ($constructor_img as $key => $image) {
                if(empty($image['image'])) continue;
                $output .= '<li><a href="'.$image['image'].'" data-width="'.$img_size[0].'" data-height="'.$img_size[1].'"';
                $output .= '</a></li>';
            }
        $output .= '</ul>';
    }else{
        $output = '<label>Bottle Color</label><ul></ul>';
    }
    echo $output;
    die();
}
```

In total there will be up to 16 list items generated by this. I need each list item to have its own class eg: list class="red", list class="green",  etc. Any idea how i go about achieving this?

Comment: Set an array prior to the loop and use an increasing counter to access the values for every new row OR set a new meta value for each product which contains that class name. Which option would you like me to explain?

Comment: you want class on li or on anchor and also  put all classes in an array and when you are iterating your image loop based on counter fecth the value from class array and insert them in your li or anchor tag

Comment: Guo Cong please mark and up-vote the answer for others help. thanks

Comment: peoples are not interested in mark and up-vote the answer for others help. Also not interested in telling that problem solved or not? wastage of effort. Deleting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution thanks to Anant. Had to declare the class array like below.

```
function get_bottle_colors() {
    if(empty($_GET['cap_id'])) return false;
    $constructor_img = get_post_meta($_GET['cap_id'], 'product_constructor_image', true);
    if(is_array($constructor_img) && count($constructor_img)>0 && !empty($constructor_img[0]['title'])){
        $output = '<label>Bottle Color</label><ul>';
        $i = 0;
        $class_array = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","n","m","n","o","p");
            foreach ($constructor_img as $key => $image) {
                if(empty($image['image'])) continue;
                $category = 9;
                $img_size = getimagesize($image['image']);
                $output .= '<li class= "'.$class_array[$i].'"><a href="'.$image['image'].'" data-width="'.$img_size[0].'" 

                data-height="'.$img_size[1].'"';
                $output .= 'data-id="'.$_GET['cap_id'].'_'.$key.'" data-part="#constructor-bottles" class="sub-caps">'.$image['title'];
                $output .= '</a></li>';     
                $i++;
            }
            $output .= '</ul>';
        }else{
            $output = '

<label>Bottle Color</label><ul></ul>';  }   echo $output;   die(); }
```